# Android room orm negative primary key autoincrement

Tags: android, android-room

I need to enable negative value primary key for the new object which has not been sent to the remote repository. Is it possible to have negative autoincrement primary key column in Room Orm?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement this functionality yourself. Room is just a thin API layer over SQLite, and SQLite does not have this option.